# cant manage ram and core settings in docker

Tags: docker, settings, ram

I am using Docker for Windows last version.
Before a week I had an update which asked me if I want to switch between HYPER-V to WSL if I remember correctly.
Swapped it and everything worked well as it should be, today I added a ram (same ram as I had, corsair vengeance 2x8gb 3200mhz ddr4).
but everything works good. I have 32 gigabyte now so I wanted to change the limit I gave to docker which was 6/16 cores and 6/16 ram. wanted to switch it up for like 12/32 ram so I was searching for the advanced setting which I used to limit the ram and cores before and I didn't manage to find it.
seems like the option just disappear.
I have to give docker more ram because I want him to run 2 programs at the same time which take more than 6gb ram.
what I have and what did I try conclusion :

1. I'm using windows.
2. I have 32 gigabyte ram.
3. I tried to reinstall docker.
4. I tried to remove the image and containers and add them again.
   still did not find the setting which I used before which is really annoying.
   any ideas ?

[image: settingsPage1]

[image: settingsPage2]

[image: settingsPage3]

[image: settingsPage4]

[image: settingsPage5]

[image: settingsPage6]

Answer (score 0):

apparently using WSL based engine removes the option "advanced" so Currently using hyper-v instead of wsl solved my problem.
thanks anyway